# Override static method in graph extension

Tags: acumatica

I don't think this is possible but thought I would ask anyway.

There is a method on the PX.Objects.AR.ARStatementPrint graph that I want to override.

Its declaration is as follows

```
public static void PrintStatements(PrintParameters filter,  List<DetailsResult> list, bool markOnly)
{   
}
```

I want to override this is my graph extension but I get errors saying cannot find the method to override in the graph etc when I use the [PXOverride]

Can you only override virtual methods with [PXOverride]?

Comment: You might be interested in this blog post: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/override-static-method.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, one can only override virtual methods with [PXOverride].